# Coordinate System in C#

Tags: c#, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to make a coordinate system with some features in C#.
I never worked with C# but think it should be similar to other languages.

I'm not sure which element is suitable for that (Panel,PictureBox,....).

The requirements are:

- I want zoom in and out
- move the left/right/down/up there
- I get values from a microcontroller and want paint them in real time

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
I dont want use other dll/libraries or programms from other people.

Thx

PS:Maybe a simple tutorial would be also great.

Comment: Are you thinking about 2D graphic or 3D?

Comment: Just in 2D. No need in 3D :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the same thing using a simple `Canvas` in WPF. So I suggest you change your platform to WPF. Zoom in/out behavior can be done using a `ScaleTransform` and move left/right/... can be done using a TranslateTransform. No need to any library, you can use geometric types int wpf such as `Path`. And set the `RenderTransform` property of every path to these transform functions.

Comment: Why WPF, what are the benefits against windows form ?

Comment: @user2261524 Vector based rendering. Support scale/translate transformations. Support data types such as `Point`, `Path`, `PathGeometry`, `StreamGeometry`. Support animations so you can build interactive maps and ...

Comment: So you used a Canvas and drawn the coordinate axis there ?

Comment: @user2261524 Yes. I'm using a `Canvas` and draw polygon, lines and even images on it. But I haven't add axis because I don't need it, however it is possible.

Comment: Any ideas how I can extend my coordinate axis ? I mean if a draw a X-axis (for time) from 0-100 and I get values over 100 is it possible that I can extend it for any value I get ?

Comment: @user2261524 you may refresh the `Canvas` after each move event. So After each move event you should draw to lines. Also if your extent is not too big you can draw two long lines in which cover the area you want as the axis.